# How to back up a site collection without Data?

Tags: backup

Is there a way to backup site collection without data? if not, is there a way restore the site collection from backup but without the data. The site collection backup is 150gb and I only need the site collection without the data in QC farm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this easily unless the site collection is a feature the defines all the lists and libraries being used. However [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/60414a6b-b944-4c89-9478-0f2a6872f018/how-to-exportbackup-a-sitecollection-excluding-content) on TechNet shows some options.

The accepted answer so it doesn't get lost:

> Too bad that scripts are using SPSolutionExporter which only available
>   for Sharepoint 2010   However, here is my powershell scripts solution
>   which for MOSS 2007 which modify from that CreateSiteTemplates.ps1.
>   Download scripts from here:
>   https://skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Code/ExportSiteTemplate.rar?cid=e44ea63872a84c5a&sc=documents
>
> 1. First, run CreateSiteTemplates.ps1 scripts to create site templates from your SourceUrl.    .\CreatesiteTemplates.ps1 -SourceURL
>      `'http://sites.demo.com/'` -SaveData 0 -SaveCurrentSite -IncludeSubSites
>      1
> 2. Then, run DownloadAndAddTemplates.ps1 script to download sitetemplates from sourceUrl and add as Custom Template
>      .\DownloadAndAddTemplates.ps1 -SourceURL `'http://sites.demo.com/`'
>      -AddCurrentSite 1 -IncludeSubSites 1   Note: please create a folder at C:\STP as default download folder before run the script
> 3. Run IISReset to make sure custom templates added take effect.
> 4. Go to Central Administration to create a new web application and new site collections based on your custom template of top source site,
>      you can find your custom template at Custom tab
> 5. Lastly, run CreateSubSites.ps1 to create subsites structure   .\CreateSubSites.ps1 -SourceUrl `"http://sites.demo.com"`
>      -DestinationUrl `"http://sites2:demo.com"`   Indeed not a perfect solution as code need some refactoring for sure and, 100% automation
>      yet, and support only 1-level subsites, but hope can give some hints
>      or tips for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look in Ave Point Backup & Restore tool but not sure...

http://www.avepoint.com/sharepoint-backup-and-restore-docave/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So there is no OOTB or other powershell way of doing this?