# export sharepoint site collection and subsites structure without content

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, export, import

I would like to export SharePoint site collection and its subsites, but the structure only and NOT the content. Then I would like to import it to another SP Server.

`Export-SPWeb` exports it with the content which I don't want as the content is so huge and I don't have disk space for a backup.

I just want the Site and subsite structure, with its site columns, content types, lists and libraries.

I have `Sharepoint server 2016 Enterprise`.
`Save site as template` is out of the question as the site has enabled publishing features and it will not install correctly in the new environment.
In the back of my mind I thought it was possible just by extracting the xml schema and generate site based on that schema.

Comment: What SharePoint version is this? I don't think this is possible with Export-SPWeb, have you considered using PnP PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the address bar type http://sitename/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx which will give you option to Save site as a Template.

do not check "Include Content" check box which will just save the site as a template without any content

This will save the site in .stp format and you will get the template under Site Action > Site settings > Site Template Gallery

and using this template you can create number of same sites.

**Source** :

[Is it possible to export a Site or Sitecollection without content](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/49d22f46-b2bf-4046-8aa3-03a9e110f4bc/is-it-possible-to-export-a-site-or-sitecollection-without-content?forum=sharepointadminlegacy)

**PowerShell scripts location**

The above process from downloading the template to creating site with the template, we can automate by executing the set of PowerShell script which is available in the below location :

https://onedrive.live.com/?id=E44EA63872A84C5A%211510&cid=E44EA63872A84C5A

**Source to script:**

[How to back up a site collection without Data?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77492/how-to-back-up-a-site-collection-without-data)

**PnP Provisioning template approach**

Similarly, if you are using SharePoint online /2019 /2016, you can use PnP provisioning template approach.

- In the PnP Provisioning template approach, you need run the **Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate** in the source site and need run the **Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate**  in the target site.
- Before running the Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate command we should have empty site in the target, just create the framework of the site - sample site without any list content type etc.

To see the example of PnP Provisioning template PowerShell, you may refer the below MSDN article :

[Introducing the PnP provisioning engine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine#apply-a-provisioning-template)